# Sqlite update query not working in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am trying to update my list item when I click on it and takes me to the page where I can edit my list items. But it is not working. Here is the code that I am using to update my data in SQLite database

Database update method:

```
public void updateTasks(Task t, String recieveduserId) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
                v.put(TASK_NAME, t.getTaskname());
                v.put(TASK_PRIOR, t.getPrior());
                v.put(TASK_DUEDATE, t.getDuedate());
                v.put(TASK_LABEL, t.getLabel());
                v.put(TASK_COMMENT, t.getComment());
                db.update(TASK_TABLE, v, "task_id="+recieveduserId,null);
                db.close();
    }
```

This is where I am trying to use the update method:
Display class:

```
public class Display extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText task_edit, date_edit, prior_edit, label_edit, comment_edit, reminder_edit;
ImageButton btn_date, btn_prior, btn_label, btn_comment, btn_reminder;
Button saveBtn, editBtn;

String getTask, getDate, getPrior, getLabel, getComment, getReminder, getId;
Cursor cr;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    task_edit = findViewById(R.id.edittask);
    date_edit = findViewById(R.id.dateedit);
    prior_edit = findViewById(R.id.prioredit);
    label_edit = findViewById(R.id.labeledit);
    comment_edit = findViewById(R.id.commentedit);
    reminder_edit = findViewById(R.id.reminderedit);

    btn_date = findViewById(R.id.btneditDate);
    btn_prior = findViewById(R.id.btneditPrior);
    btn_label = findViewById(R.id.btneditLabel);
    btn_comment = findViewById(R.id.btneditComment);
    btn_reminder = findViewById(R.id.btneditReminder);

    saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    editBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnedit);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    task_edit.setEnabled(false);
    date_edit.setEnabled(false);
    prior_edit.setEnabled(false);
    label_edit.setEnabled(false);
    comment_edit.setEnabled(false);
    reminder_edit.setEnabled(false);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        getTask= null;
        getDate = null;
        getPrior = null;
    } else {
        getTask = extras.getString("task");
        getDate = extras.getString("duedate");
        getPrior = extras.getString("priority");
        getId = extras.getString("id");
        task_edit.setText(getTask);
        date_edit.setText(getDate);
        prior_edit.setText(getPrior);

        cr =  dbHelper.getDetails(getTask, getDate, getPrior);

        if(cr.getCount()>0) {
            if(cr.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    getLabel = cr.getString(0);
                    getComment = cr.getString(1);

                    label_edit.setText(getLabel);
                    comment_edit.setText(getComment);

                } while(cr.moveToNext());
            }
        }

    }

    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            task_edit.setEnabled(true);
            date_edit.setEnabled(true);
            prior_edit.setEnabled(true);
            label_edit.setEnabled(true);
            comment_edit.setEnabled(true);
            reminder_edit.setEnabled(true);

            final String name = task_edit.getText().toString();
            final String date = date_edit.getText().toString();
            final String prior = prior_edit.getText().toString();
            final String label = label_edit.getText().toString();
            final String comment = comment_edit.getText().toString();

            saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Task t = new Task();
                    t.setTaskname(name);
                    t.setDuedate(date);
                    t.setPrior(prior);
                    t.setLabel(label);
                    t.setComment(comment);
                    dbHelper.updateTasks(t,getId);

                    task_edit.setEnabled(false);
                    date_edit.setEnabled(false);
                    prior_edit.setEnabled(false);
                    label_edit.setEnabled(false);
                    comment_edit.setEnabled(false);
                    reminder_edit.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
```

Model class:

```
public class Task {

String taskname;
String username;
String duedate;
String prior;
String label;
Date reminder;
String comment;



public String getTaskname() {
    return taskname;
}

public void setTaskname(String taskname) {
    this.taskname = taskname;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getDuedate() {
    return duedate;
}

public void setDuedate(String duedate) {
    this.duedate = duedate;
}

public Date getReminder() {
    return reminder;
}

public void setReminder(Date reminder) {
    this.reminder = reminder;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getPrior() {
    return prior;
}

public void setPrior(String prior) {
    this.prior = prior;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *But it is not working* What makes you think that it is not working? does it crash for example. First thing to try is to place a breakpoint on this line `dbHelper.updateTasks(t,getId);` run  in debug and check the values are as expected (especially the **id**) when the debugger window apears. If the **id** is wrong (should be a numeric greater than 0) then you need to look at why `getId = extras.getString("id");` is not geting the correct value (getting the wrong id is very common).

Comment: it crashes and gives and gives an outofboundexception in array. There's something wrong with the array but I don't know what it is and how to fix it

Comment: i'm using onswipe method to delete it. I think that's where the problem is